# Send a POST request to one page but redirect to another

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sms-gateway

Really having trouble trying to implement this in my controller. Essentially as it stands I have a controller than when it completes passes the user to a URL as below:

```
    <HttpPost()>
    Function Create(job As Job) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            db.Jobs.Add(job)
            db.SaveChanges()
            Dim url As String = "/RequestedService/AddService/" + job.JobId.ToString()
            Return Redirect(url)
        End If

        Return View(job)
    End Function
```

However I am trying to implement the functionality to send an SMS each time this controller is called and have got this working with a URL like (made up without username or password):
http://go.bulksms.com:1557/send?username=fred&message=hello
This needs to be accessed via an HTTP post request. I understand I can return this URL in the 'Return Redirect' above but I want both to happen (the redirect and the post on this link sending the SMS) and ideally I want the user to be redirected to the page as it happens now but the SMS to be sent in the background. How would I implement this?

Comment: The most that you can do, it's making an ajax called from your client and return in your actions a `JavascriptResult` and then in the success method do another ajax type post with url of the action and the parameters that you need to pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. New code is added between two comment line. You can also consult this [url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) for details, if it's a POST you might have to pass some form data, it's all described in the link above.:

```
<HttpPost()>
    Function Create(job As Job) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            db.Jobs.Add(job)
            db.SaveChanges()
            'Sending SMS here: (start)
            Dim request as WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://go.bulksms.com:1557/send?username=fred&message=hello")
            request.Method = "POST"
            Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

            'end
            Dim url As String = "/RequestedService/AddService/" + job.JobId.ToString()
            Return Redirect(url)
        End If

        Return View(job)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect is always a `GET` request

for posting to the different URL , You need to call it from your code using `HttpWebRequest` class.

Comment: Ah thanks for the heads up on the GET. How exactly do I call it using HttpWebRequest, I am not quite sure how this would happen in my code as I have tried using intellisense to find HttpWebRequest but no luck (sorry I am fairly novice to ASP)